# how to render an SVG from a server and still have the option to interpolate JSX into it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

**My goal is to fetch from my own server an SVG and to interpolate the `children` attribute after the `<polygon></polygon>` tag.**

I am doing this is to add an interactive layer that can be modified by react.

So far I am able to achieve that by serving  my SVG via react app, but I want to avoid it for security reasons.

This is my progress so far:

```js
const App = ({children}) => {
  
return (
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width="24"
      height="24"
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      fill="none"
      stroke="#6b9bd2"
      stroke-width="3"
      stroke-linecap="round"
      stroke-linejoin="arcs"
    >
  <polygon points="12 2 15.09 8.26 22 9.27 17 14.14 18.18 21.02 12 17.77 5.82 21.02 7 14.14 2 9.27 8.91 8.26 12 2"></polygon>
    {children}
    </svg>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**My ideal solution** should look something like this:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

type ViewBox = {
  x1: string;
  x2: string;
  y1: string;
  y2: string;
};

interface SVGElement {
  svgContent: string;
  viewBox: ViewBox;
}

const App: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [content, setContent] = useState<SVGElement | undefined>();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/get-svg-content")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setContent(data))
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
  }, []);

  if (content === undefined) return <></>;

  const viewBox = `${content.viewBox.x1} ${content.viewBox.x2} ${content.viewBox.y1} ${content.viewBox.y2}`;
  return (
    <svg viewBox={viewBox}>
      {content.svgContent}
      {children}
    </svg>
  );
};

export default App;


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

[codeSandbox](https://lfbqw1.csb.app/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using `rehype-react` - https://github.com/rehypejs/rehype-react.

If you store your SVG as an XML in a database for example, then retrieving it as a string in the client-side, this package allows you to render same string as an SVG (or any other tag).

This method might expose you to  [cross-site scripting (XSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), so you should consider using `react-sanitize` in order to sanitize the string before rendering it.

Using the methods mentioned above, you can render your SVG elements inside the `react` client, and still implement your component logic around the rendered content.